# SparkException: Values to assemble cannot be null after adding vector column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark 2.1 (standalone) on Windows. Unable to save spark dataframe to parquet file after adding VectorAssembler column.
No problems to save dataframe before vector column, all "features" is not null (NVL used)

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("RandomForestModelML").setMaster("local")
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

  val df = sparkSession.read
    .option("header", true)
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .csv("C:\\tmp\\file2.csv")
    .createOrReplaceTempView("features")

  var data = sparkSession.sql("select cast(NVL(c9003,0) as int) as c9003.. from features")

  data = data.withColumnRenamed("target", "label")
  val ignored = List("label", "c0025", "c9052", "c0019")

  val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(data.columns.diff(ignored))
    .setOutputCol("features")
  data = featureAssembler.transform(data)
  data.printSchema()
  data.show(5)

  data.write.format("parquet").save("C:\\tmp\\features.parquet")
```

Output for printSchema and show(5):

```
root
 |-- c9003: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c0022: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c9014: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c9008: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- a8401: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c0021: double (nullable = true)
 |-- c0025: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d1417: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- d0006: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c9052: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c0023: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- d1501: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c0020: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- d0007: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c0024: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c4018: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- at180: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c1421: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)


+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+
|c9003|c0022|c9014|c9008|a8401|c0021|               c0025|d1417|d0006|c9052|c0023|d1501|c0020|d0007|c0024|c4018|at180|c1421|label|            features|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+
|   10|    1|    4|   53|    0|  0.0|FHB KERESKEDELMI ...|    0|    0|    P|    2|    0|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|    1|    0|(16,[0,1,2,3,8,10...|
|   10|    1|    3|   69|    0| 0.01|        MKB BANK ZRT|    1|    0|    P|    0|    0|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|    1|    0|(16,[0,1,2,3,5,6,...|
|  100|    2|    4|   57|    0| 0.24|SANTANDER CONSUME...|    1|   18|    P|    2|    1|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|    1|    0|[100.0,2.0,4.0,57...|
|  100|    2|    5|   55|    0| 0.09|SANTANDER CONSUME...|    0|    0|    P|    0|    0|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|    1|    0|(16,[0,1,2,3,5,10...|
|   10|    3|    2|   65|    4| 0.23|RAIFFEISEN BANK ZRT.|    2|   14|    P|    0|    2|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|    1|    0|[10.0,3.0,2.0,65....|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

And exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$3: (struct<c9003_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c0022_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c9014_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c9008_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,a8401_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c0021:double,d1417_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,d0006_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c0023_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,d1501_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c0020_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,d0007_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c0024_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c4018_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,at180_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double,c1421_double_vecAssembler_41f4486b7bab:double>) => vector)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Values to assemble cannot be null.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:98)
    ... 16 more
```

UPDATE:
Looks like issue in data, but I do not understand where. I've tried to remove all columns except "label" and "c9003", it is working OK. It it is working OK with some other columns, but raise exception on c9014. Now I'm trying this query for dataframe

```
var data = sparkSession.sql("select NVL(target,0) as target, cast(NVL(c9003,0) as int) as c9003, cast(NVL(c9014,0) as int) as c9014 from features where c9014 is not null")
data.show(20)
+------+-----+-----+
|target|c9003|c9014|
+------+-----+-----+
|     0|   10|    4|
|     0|   10|    3|
|     0|  100|    4|
|     0|  100|    5|
|     0|   10|    2|
|     0|   10|    6|
|     0|   10|    2|
|     0|   90|    4|
|     0|   80|    4|
|     0|   80|    5|
|     0|   10|    2|
|     0|   90|    8|
|     0|   90|    8|
|     0|   90|    8|
|     0|   90|    4|
|     0|   80|    5|
|     0|   80|    2|
|     0|   80|    2|
|     0|   90|    7|
|     0|   90|    8|
+------+-----+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

After adding vector column:

```
root
 |-- label: string (nullable = false)
 |-- c9003: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c9014: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

UPDATE2: Looks like issue in memory/data volume. I've tried to add filters in SQL:

1. cast(NVL(c9014,9999) as int)>1000 -> it is working OK
2. cast(NVL(c9014,9999) as int)<=1000 -> it is working OK
3. no filter on c9014 -> raising exception

Any hints on memory tuning ?

Comment: can you share few lines of ur dataset?

Comment: I've updated main post, looks like issue in column c9014

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, issue in SQL query "cast(NVL(c9014,0) as int) as c9014"
this code can produce NULLs, CAST() should be used before the NVL().